# Implement excel Loopup Function in scala

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark, scala-collections

I have two Arrays

```
arrayLong = Array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i')

arrayShort = Array('c', 'h')
```

I have to form a third array of same length of `arrayLong` with `1` if that position value in present in `arrayShort` else `0`.

For above example I need output `Array(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0)` as only `c, h` are present in `arrayShort` so their positions are updates to `1`.

Comment: What does this have to do with spark?

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use map with an if else

```
val arrayShort=Array ('c','h')
val arrayLong=Array('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i')
val result = arrayLong.map(f => if(arrayShort.contains(f)) 1 else 0)
```

Result

```
result: Array[Int] = Array(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0)
```

Comment: arrayLong is a very long Array and going through all its values would be a very Heavy Operation.

Comment: But you want to convert all the values right? Can there the duplicate values like `arrayLong = Array('a','a')` and should they stay there?

Comment: I dont want exactly to convert I have a to form an Array for same lengeth with only 0's and 1's. I thought of declaring a array of 0's of length LongArray and then updating it by iterating over shortArray.

Answer (score 1):

```
def lookup[T](in: Array[T], values: Array[T]): Array[Int] = {
  val valuesSet = new mutable.HashSet[T] ++ values
  in.map(i => if (valuesSet.contains(i)) 1 else 0)
}

lookup(Array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i'), Array('c', 'h'))
```

Note: the conversion to set makes this function runtime `O(n + m)`

Comment: arrayLong is a very long Array and going through all its values would be a very Heavy Operation.

Comment: Just use a mutable `HashSet` and the whole algorithm will go down to `O (n + m)`.

Comment: @Harshit but you have to at least look at each element once to know if they belong to smaller array, don't you?

Comment: @bottaio that's an immutable set, so it's backed by a trie. It runs in `O(n lg n)`.

Comment: @bottaio I agree I have to lookup, But wont it be a good way to look values from small array into big and update third one on basisi of that.

Comment: @devouredelysium it's backed by HashTrieSet - collisions are resolved by a TrieSet so it's still O(1) lookup

Comment: @Harshit but how do you know where this value is in large array if you are not going to look through large array at least once?

Comment: @bottaio you said it yourself: it's a `trie`. Trie's operations are `O(lg n)`, possibly with a high branching factor.

Comment: @devouredelysium there's a difference between a HashSet and a HashTrieSet - both of them start with hashing element and looking them up in lookup table - only when collision occurs, they use additional structures to resolve them: for HashSet that's a linked list, for HashTrieSet that's a Trie. Saying that HashTrieSet has `O(lg n)` lookup is similar to saying that HashSet has `O(n)` lookup what, in normal circumstances (pathological hash function), is just silly.

Comment: @bottaio Please check the API documentation. That's not how it works and it's easy to understand why. Were HashtrieSets implemented as you suggest, every insertion / deletion operation would require a full recreation of the HashSet that you're so obsessed about, making it roughly `O(n)`. So adding all those objects would be `O(n * n)`.

Comment: @devouredelysium every day one learns something new, thanks! I was totally wrong there

Comment: @bottaio: that's what stackoverflow is for :)

Comment: @Harshit `indexOf` is not a magical constant function - it actually looks through the 
whole large array

Comment: @bottaio You are Correct but I would be looking for smaller number of values. I have 10000 values in large array and 10 in shorarray.